# Force UIButton titleLabel text to show Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a button that is made in the following manner. The label of my button is truncated as I have shown at the bottom

```
let width = self.view.frame.size.width
let label = UIButton()


// label setup
label.setTitle("Going Out", for: .normal)
label.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "avenir-next-regular", size: 8)
label.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
label.layer.zPosition = 8
label.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
label.frame = CGRect(x: 3 * width / 32, y: width / 6, width: width / 6, height: width / 8)
view.addSubview(label)
```

This produes a button with the text: Go..Out
How can I force this to show: Going Out
While **NOT** sizeToFit() and shrinking my UIButton

Comment: from what I know, it is not possible to force the text size to remain, and yet maintain the size of your button. Its like you want force your way to store 600ml of water inside a 500ml water bottle. It just don't make any sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 Button text auto resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082039/swift-3-button-text-auto-resizing)

Comment: Maybe his button insets is truncating his text. His button only has two words "Going Out"...

Answer (score 0):

Try below, should work:

```
label.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```